# Creating a link through button

Tags: javascript, html

Anybody please explain how to create a button which redirects to a link/website by clicking on it.
Please provide a code as example.

Comment: While you for some reason have gotten answers to this, Stack Overflow shouldn't be considered a code-writing service. For future questions please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <button onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">redirect me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Javascript. The button code will be as follows:

```
<button onclick="redirect()">Take me to google</button>

<script>
function redirect() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the btn class for `<a>` with bootstrap like this

```
<a href = "http://yourlink.com" class = "btn btn-danger">Link button</a>
```

Don't forget to use bootstrap cdn in `<head>`:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```